# What does 握草 mean?

Tags: translation

On google it says it means Wò cǎo, hold grass. On my translation app it means grip the grass! I know this term means like an expression of surprise, and similar to the curse word f*ck, but I’m not exactly sure.

For example in this passage: 
守灵的李七婶心里直叫：握草，听说过诈尸，没成想，今儿真遇上了！

What does it mean, how would I translate this passage? Please give me some clarification on this term!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

握草，in that context as you suggested, is a curse word like "f*ck", "damn". There are couple of more variants of it such as 我草，我靠，我操.

握草 can be a way to get around the censorship of rude words in web posts.